# Why is SIGAR returning NaN or zero randomly

Tags: scala, nan, sigar

Trying to run [SIGAR](http://www.hyperic.com/products/sigar) rapidly to get a number of hardware metric samples, and I see this behavior:

```
val sig: Sigar = new Sigar()
val steady_cpu: Double = (for (i <- 1 to 100) yield sig.getCpuPerc().getUser()).sum / 100.0
```

where steady_cpu results to NaN. Looking at the generated list, the NaN's come from the getUser() call returning NaN

Answer (score 3):

General issue seems to be that SIGAR calls are potentially stateful, and calling the functions too quickly does not give SIGAR time to rebuild it's internal state. I'd guess that they are counting CPU cycles or something similar, which is typically an approximate science, and if you call functions too rapidly the internal libraries end up dividing by zero. The fix is to add a short sleep between calls:

```
val sig: Sigar = new Sigar()
val steady_cpu: Double = (for (i <- 1 to 100) yield {
  Thread.sleep(10); 
  sig.getCpuPerc().getUser()
}).sum / 100.0
```

Comment: Division by zero does not yield a `NaN`, it yields an `Infinity`.

Comment: Ah good point. Do you have an alternate explanation for receiving NaNs from the library?

Comment: zero divided by zero yelds to NaN: if the statistic gathered is itself approximated to zero, as the elapsed time is, then NaN is a perfectly reasonable result.